# Column order when pivoting dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataframe like this

```
data_dict = {'Date': [2010,2010,2010], 'Description': ['ZZ','XX','YY'], 'Value': [10,20,30], 'ID':[1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

   Date Description  ID  Value
0  2010          ZZ   1     10
1  2010          XX   2     20
2  2010          YY   3     30
```

I now want to pivot my data like this

```
df_piv = df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Description', values='Value')
```

which gives me this

```
Description  XX  YY  ZZ
Date                   
2010         20  30  10
```

How can I instead of having a alphabetic column order, order my columns by my ID column to get

```
Description  ZZ  XX  YY
Date                   
2010         10  20  30
```

Possible solution:

```
 description = list(df['Description'])
 df_piv[description]
```

Comment: Thanks for putting the `data_dict` in your question, makes testing much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you need to call `reindex` (reindex_axis is going to be deprecated)

```
In [15]: column_order = ['ZZ', 'XX', 'YY']

In [16]: df_piv.reindex(column_order, axis=1)
Out[16]: 
Description  ZZ  XX  YY
Date                   
2010         10  20  30
```

Answer (score 1):

consider this alternative solution:

first create a dictionary which maps 'ID' column to 'Description' column

```
to_dict = df.loc[:,['ID','Description']].set_index('ID').to_dict().get('Description')
```

than create the pivot with columns from which you want the rearrangement order and than simply rename the columns from the dictionary created above.

```
df.pivot(index='Date',columns='ID', values='Value').rename(columns=to_dict)
```

You may want to use this alternative where the number of columns to be rearranged is quite large and it will be tedious to manually type the rearrangement order through pandas.reindex function.

if you wish you can add this additional line of code

```
df.columns.name = df.columns.name.replace('ID','Decription')
```